"tsc command not found" even though i have installed typescript
How to export typescript into VS-code after installing node-modules (includs typescript) globally into my Mac?
This is my first command: npm install -g typescript
as showin in terminal.
Then when I tried to work in VS-code, "tsc" command doesn't work.
Is there an export path I should work with?
I tried to install typescript locally inside this working file, and it worked. But why didn't it work with the global installation?



If you did everything but still get an error like tsc not found then you should use tsc in locally not generally. In this case, you can try installing a local version of TypeScript instead of installing it globally.
npm install typescript --save-dev

You can no longer use the tsc command directly. Instead, you can run the tsc command using the npx tool.
npx tsc script.ts

This worked for me. I hope it works for u too. Good luck!
